# Form is not submit handler is not called

Tags: 7, forms

I have this code for calling a form and than submit it..

```
<?php 
// hook_menu
function pricepackages_menu()
{
    $items = array();
    $items['membership/packages'] = array(
        'title' => t('Manage Membership Packages'),
        'page callback' => 'drupal_get_form',
        'page arguments' => array('pricepackages_form'),
       //'access callback' => TRUE,
       'access arguments' => array('access administration pages'),
    );
    return $items;
}
// FORM SHOW HOOK
function pricepackages_form($form, &$form_state)
{
    $form = array();

    $form['packagename'] = array(
        '#type' => 'textfield',
        '#title' => 'Package Name',
        //'attribute' => array('class' => 'package'),
        '#required' => TRUE,
    );
    $form['packageDescp'] = array(
        '#type' => 'textfield',
        '#title' => 'Package Short Description',
        //'attribute' => array('class' => 'package'),
        '#required' => FALSE,
    );
    $form['price'] = array(
        '#type' => 'textfield',
        '#title' => 'Package Price',
        //'attribute' => array('class' => 'package'),
        '#required' => TRUE,
    );
    $form['submit'] = array(
        '#type' => 'submit',
        '#value' => t('Submit'),
    );
    $form['submit'][] = array('package_get_form'=> array());

    return $form;
}

function package_get_form($form, &$form_state)
{
    drupal_set_message('working');
?>
    <script language="javascript">
        alert("aaa");
    </script>
<?php
return; 
    }
?>
```

but this one is not wokring proerly and form is not being submitted on the specific form...
neither its showing alert or message...

please help me...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this:

`$form['submit'][] = array('package_get_form'=> array());`

to this:

`$form['#submit'][] = 'package_get_form';`

btw.

```
function package_get_form($form, &$form_state)
{
    drupal_set_message('working');
?>
    <script language="javascript">
        alert("aaa");
    </script>
<?php
return; 
}
?>
```

This looks really messy. Try that instead:

```
function package_get_form($form, &$form_state) {
  debug('test');
}
```

But the best option would be to use standard submit handler instead declaring your own name convention:

```
function pricepackages_form_submit($form, &$form_state) {
...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the pound sign where you add the submit handler:

```
  $form['#submit'][] = 'package_get_form';
```

`$form['#submit']` should be an linear array, and each value should be a valid function.

Submit handlers will get `$form` and `$form_state` as arguments in that order. 
If the submit handler is not included, you can run `form_load_include` to make sure the file is included before calling the submit handler.

Also, note that you can add an implicit submit handler if you define a function named `pricepackages_form_submit`.